# Can someone help me with formatting this to the form of a phone number: 000-000-0000

Tags: python

How can I print the number like this "641-648-4685". The code works for me but the number formating is the only problem

```
    def __init__( self, name, area_code, number, is_active = True):
        self.name = name
        self.area_code = area_code
        self.number = number
        self.is_active = is_active
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area_code)+'-'+str(self.number)+" ("+self.name+")"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.area_code == other.area_code and self.number == other.number:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def activate(self):
        self.is_active = True

    def deactivate(self):
        self.is_active = False

phone1 = Phone("HU", "641","6484685")
phone1.deactivate()
print(phone1)
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @dfundako when I run my code it returns 641-6484685 when I need it to return     
 641-648-4685

Comment: In the part where it formats the number, are there 2 hyphens?

Comment: Can you post an instance?

Comment: @dfundako yes there are two hyphens ignore

Comment: @JLeno46 the instance is my code prints 641-6484685 (HU) I want it to 641-648-4685 (HU)

Comment: I mean, can you post an object of your class? You provide a desired output but no input.

Comment: @JLeno46 Sorry I've edited the post and put the input. phone1 = Phone("HU", "641","6484685")
phone1.deactivate()
print(phone1)

Answer (score 1):

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.area_code)+'-'+str(self.number)[0:3] +'-'+str(self.number)[3:]+" ("+self.name+")"
```

might be more what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3, then you can use f-strings formatting

```
return f'{self.area_code}-{self.number[:3]}-{self.number[3:]} ({self.name})'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.area_code}-{self.number[:3]}-{self.number[3:]} {self.name}'
```

Considering that both `area_code` and `number` are already `strings` there's no need for `str()`

I suggest a formatted string for extra clarity.